# How to Store login information in WPF and reuse it ? (Cookies functionality of ASP.Net)

Tags: c#, wpf, isolatedstoragefile

I have tried a lot, but not able to find a perfect solution for same.

I am wokring on a WPF Desktop application,

Username, Database name ,server name and password.. those information user entered for successful access/login into the system. I want to store those information in some memory and reuse it after session/application end.

like in gmail.com, we don't need to enter our email id to access it. (It by default available, if we used earlier).

Most relevant solution - http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/955/using-isolatedstoragefile-to-store-data-in-wpf-application-class-event

I have tried to use list to store data and access, but not able to do it.

Many thanks in advance. (this is my first time to ask any question online)

Comment: What is your specific problem, when you tried to implement it yourself which specific step fail/not know how to do? Right now your question is too broad and needs to be narrowed down to the specific issue that is keeping you from implementing it your self.

Answer (score 1):

**Application Settings - cannot be changed during the running of a program**
I assume that you are not allowing user to change values like Database name and server name which is normally stored in application setting which has a great documentation at [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) .

**Storing of Connection String**
Connection String are always stored at the config file of your project which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ApplicationDbConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DATABASE\Trackboard.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and can be access by the following code:

```
 private static string ConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationDbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

**User Settings - settings can be changed during running of a program**
For settings like user name and password I would recommend you to store it at User settings which also has a great documentation at [msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patrickdanino/archive/2008/07/23/user-settings-in-wpf.aspx)(simpler but not very complete) and [code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25829/User-Settings-Applied)(Very complete but takes time to go through).

Hope this helps!